# springboot use redis manage session,session.invalidate()delete session,but redis session time become 300s

Tags: spring-boot, session, redis, spring-session

I use Redis as a session manager, the `application.properties` is

```
spring.session.timeout=1500
```

when I add a session, Redis TTL = 1800

```
@PostMapping("/session/add")
public String sessionAdd(HttpSession session) {
    User user = new User();
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    return "ok";
}
```

when I delete the session, Redis TTL = 300

```
@GetMapping("session/logout")
public void sessionLogout(HttpSession session) {
    session.invalidate();
}
```

my question is

1. add a session, I expect Redis TTL = 1500, but the truth is 1800
2. delete the session, the redis should remove the key, but it exists and TTL = 300

where does the `300` come from?